# Passing loop variable to sh in Jenkinsfile doesn't scope correctly

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to dynamically create jobs in a Jenkinsfile using the following loop. The jobs are created correctly, and the task names show up in Jenkins with the correct name (e.g. `ubuntu:bionic`).

However, the within each task the `sh` commands seem to not have access to `images` as `${images[i]}` is being evaluated to `null` (e.g. `sh ci/script.sh null`). So this doesn't seem to be the same as other single-vs-double quote issues with string interpolation.

```
def images = ["ubuntu:bionic", "ubuntu:xenial"]
def tasks = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
  tasks["${images[i]}"] = {
    node {
      lock("build") {
        stage('checkout') {
          checkout scm
        }
        stage('test') {
          sh "ci/script.sh ${images[i]}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

stage("matrix") {
  parallel tasks
}
```

How can I build these dynamic commands correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure you create in the loop and assign to `tasks["${images[i]}"]` is evaluated lazily and it seems like it processes `images.getAt(i)` with the current `i` value, which in this case is equal to `2` in both cases. Take a look at following example with some additional printing of current `i` state (I've skipped `scm checkout` int this short example):

```groovy
def images = ["ubuntu:bionic", "ubuntu:xenial"]
def tasks = [:]

for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
  println "Using i = ${i}"                             // <- first print
  tasks["${images[i]}"] = {
    node {
      lock("build") {
        stage('checkout') {
          echo "ok"
        }
        stage('test') {
          println "Print i inside stage = ${i}"        // <- second print
          echo "Echo i inside stage = ${i}"            // <- third print
          sh "ci/script.sh ${images[i]}".toString()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

stage("matrix") {
  parallel tasks
}
```

When we run it we will see something like this in the console:

```
[Pipeline] echo
Using i = 0
[Pipeline] echo
Using i = 1
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (matrix)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] { (Branch: ubuntu:bionic)
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] { (Branch: ubuntu:xenial)
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] node
[ubuntu:bionic] Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] node
[ubuntu:xenial] Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline@2
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] {
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] {
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] lock
[ubuntu:bionic] Trying to acquire lock on [build]
[ubuntu:bionic] Lock acquired on [build]
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] {
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] lock
[ubuntu:xenial] Trying to acquire lock on [build]
[ubuntu:xenial] Found 0 available resource(s). Waiting for correct amount: 1.
[ubuntu:xenial] [build] is locked, waiting...
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] { (checkout)
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] echo
[ubuntu:bionic] ok
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] }
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] // stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] { (test)
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] echo
[ubuntu:bionic] Print i inside stage = 2
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] echo
[ubuntu:bionic] Echo i inside stage = 2
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] sh
[ubuntu:bionic] [test-pipeline] Running shell script
[ubuntu:bionic] + ci/script.sh null
[ubuntu:bionic] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline@tmp/durable-998289d1/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline@tmp/durable-998289d1/script.sh: ci/script.sh: not found
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] }
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] // stage
[ubuntu:xenial] Lock acquired on [build]
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] }
[ubuntu:bionic] Lock released on resource [build]
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] {
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] // lock
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] }
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] { (checkout)
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] // node
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:bionic] }
[ubuntu:bionic] Failed in branch ubuntu:bionic
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] echo
[ubuntu:xenial] ok
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] }
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] // stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] { (test)
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] echo
[ubuntu:xenial] Print i inside stage = 2
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] echo
[ubuntu:xenial] Echo i inside stage = 2
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] sh
[ubuntu:xenial] [test-pipeline@2] Running shell script
[ubuntu:xenial] + ci/script.sh null
[ubuntu:xenial] /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline@2@tmp/durable-b1807fa2/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline@2@tmp/durable-b1807fa2/script.sh: ci/script.sh: not found
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] }
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] // stage
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] }
[ubuntu:xenial] Lock released on resource [build]
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] // lock
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] }
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] // node
[Pipeline] [ubuntu:xenial] }
[ubuntu:xenial] Failed in branch ubuntu:xenial
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have used `println` inside the stage on purpose, because this is not a Jenkins pipeline step, but simple Groovy method. As you can see it gets evaluated when the parallel execution happens in `matrix` stage. Each Groovy closure is associated with bindings - its local state of variables. It looks like it contains `images` and `i` bindings and it tracks changes of the state of `i` variable. That is why it tries to access `images[2]` when evaluating `sh` step.

### Solution

There is a simple solution to this problem. You can replace `for-loop` with `for-each`. Consider following example:

```groovy
def images = ["ubuntu:bionic", "ubuntu:xenial"]
def tasks = [:]

images.each { image ->
  tasks["${image}"] = {
    node {
      lock("build") {
        stage('checkout') {
          checkout scm
        }
        stage('test') {
          sh "ci/script.sh ${image}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

stage("matrix") {
  parallel tasks
}
```

Console output:

```
[ubuntu:bionic] [test-pipeline] Running shell script
[ubuntu:bionic] + ci/script.sh ubuntu:bionic
[ubuntu:xenial] [test-pipeline@2] Running shell script
[ubuntu:xenial] + ci/script.sh ubuntu:xenial
```

---

You can find explanation of global scope of `i` variable in [Pipeline - Parallel execution of tasks](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922168-Pipeline-Parallel-execution-of-tasks) article on CloudBees:

> ***Note:** Variables define outside the `for` block are not local, but global to the script. Testing the option 2, you will notice that variable `i` prints always value 4, whereas `index` increases from 0 to 3 and `branch` from 1 to 4.*

Comment: This is very helpful, but the link doesn't mention anything about the scope here.  I'm trying to understand why the each statement works but for (foo in bar) does not.  Any pointers?